# I have internal stage data in DEV (snowflake) but want to move the same to PROD without loading again from source (don't want to use PUT again)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Example :

```
use role abc;
use warehouse xyz;
use database DEV;
use schema foo;

list @user/table_name/000000_0.csv.part.00.gz (internal stage file uploaded using PUT into DEV database)
```

BUT, I want to move this internal stage from DEV to PROD database. I googled but internal movement seems not possible in SF... any alternate way to do this? I have huge TBs of data loaded to DEV stages.

How can I achieve this in snowflake?

Comment: An intermediate temp location can be used to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

There's no command to move ***files*** in a Snowflake managed stage internally. You'd need to GET the files to a temporary location out of Snowflake and PUT them to a new stage.

You can move the ***data*** from one internal stage to another stage by doing a COPY INTO a transient table (any table type works, but transient will not have time travel that you don't need for this), and then doing a COPY INTO the new stage.

The files will not be the same as the original. Although they'll have the same rows, they may contain a different number of rows per file and different row orders. You're also limited in the types of files you can use when doing a COPY INTO a stage - CSV, Parquet, and JSON.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html

Answer (score 0):

and what are you trying to achieve in the end? Because what you can do is simply move the loaded data (assuming ofc they are sitting on the same deployment).

Snowflake also allows 0-copy cloning, which is a very nice feature but I'm not sure it's exactly one fitting for dev/prod scenario:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-clone.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the recent COPY FILES which allows to copy files from and to named stages, as the following table illustrates:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-files

[image: source target stages]